# How to configure maintenance pages on Passenger suburi deployments

Tags: url-rewriting, passenger, phusion

I am trying to get a maintenance page setup for a suburi deployment on Phusion Passenger for a rails app.  All the documentation shows DocumentRoot ReWrite rules, which don't appear (don't think they should) rewrite on suburis.  I tried hacking around on the ReWrite rules to point at the suburi, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Has anyone been able to get a setup which works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having exactly the same problem.
Although I am using the before filter way, I actually hate this method.

### update and answer

#### this will work if I have several sub-uris, the only missing thing here is that I can not set the header to 503, because ErrorDocument is rely on a static file which I can not determine where it is in runtime.

assume app1 and app2 is one of my sub-uri

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/system/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)(/|/.*)?$ /$1/system/maintenance.html [L]

RailsBaseURI /app1
RailsBaseURI /app2
```

Comment: Let me know if the above works for you, and I will flag it as the answer.

Comment: I finally had time to test your rewrite rule, and I found it will have problem if I have several sub-uri when applying your last rule. I modified it a little, and post it in my answer

Comment: you can use multiple error documents, one per Directory directive

Answer (score 0):

So I finally had some time to work on this and found that you can actually use the mod_rewrite method of handling maintenance page with some tweaks.  Remember that for sub-domains there is a symbolic link created in the root directory to public directory of the application.  Now if the public directory includes the maintenance file (or in a sub-directory) you can wire up mod_rewrite to find it.

For example assume application is named **app1**, and **maintenance.html** file is stored in a subdirectory **system** in the **public** directory.  Here are the lines in the apache config file and it does not appear to matter whether it is declared before or after the *RailsBaseURI /app1* line

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app1/system/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /app1/system/maintenance.html [L]

RailsBaseURI /app1
```